# How to remove icon of gui from taskbar in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using `tkinter` for making a gui,  with `-topmost` and `overrideredirect` as True.
I don't want to show it's icon in taskbar. I tried using `state` function but it doesn't work for doing this. My code:

```
from tkinter import Tk

def dragwin(event):
     x = root.winfo_pointerx() - _offsetx
     y = root.winfo_pointery() - _offsety
     root.geometry(f"+{x}+{y}")


 def clickwin(event):
     global _offsetx, _offsety
     _offsetx = event.x
     _offsety = event.y

root = Tk()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.attributes("-topmost", True)
root.configure(background="black")
root.attributes('-alpha', 0.7)

# For motion of Window
root.bind('<Button-1>', clickwin)
root.bind('<B1-Motion>', dragwin)

root.mainloop()
```

I am using python 3.8.5 and Visual Studio Code. 
All code suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You don't want to show the icon in taskbar? `overrideredirect` removes the icon from taskbar too.

Comment: This code seems to work perfectly for me. What's your operating system?

Comment: @CoolCloud But it is showing it in my pc

Comment: @SamMatzko I am on windows 10

Comment: Include screenshot maybe

Comment: @CoolCloud As I answered it is anonymously showing it in taskbar.

Comment: Are we supposed to predict the image of this? Things will be much easier with a proper screenshot of the issue

Comment: @CoolCloud Now, when I am doing so it is hiding the icon in taskbar. I don't know how it showed me before but now the issue is sorted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I am using powershell for trying code and at that stage I found that even after overrideredirect as true it is showing me the icon in taskbar, and that still shows it even when I ran the overrideredirect again.
I think it is anonymous.